# Find phone numbers with unexpected characters using SQL in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find rows where the phone number field contains unexpected characters.

Most of the values in this field look like:

```
123456-7890
```

This is expected. However, we are also seeing character values in this field such as * and #.

I want to find all rows where these unexpected character values exist.

Expected:

- Numbers are expected
- Hyphen with numbers is expected (hyphen alone is not)
- NULL is expected
- Empty is expected

Tried this:

```
WHERE phone_num is not like ' %[0-9,-,' ' ]%
```

Still getting rows where phone has numbers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you post code that creates and loads a schema, more folks will be interested in answering. It is easy to do and will allow us to visualize your desired outcome with your actual data. More insights here: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This tool can be used for generating an [ASCII Table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/). Thanks

Comment: The like operator in Oracle SQL does not work with character classes or alternation as expressed in your like statement above, instead you would need to use one of the regular expression functions such as `REGEX_LIKE`

Answer (score 3):

from https://regexr.com/3c53v address you can edit regex to match your needs.

I am going to use example regex for this purpose

```
select * from Table1
Where NOT REGEXP_LIKE(PhoneNumberColumn, '^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`regexp_like()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm).

```
...
WHERE regexp_like(phone_num, '[^ 0123456789-]|^-|-$')
```

`[^ 0123456789-]` matches any character that is not a space nor a digit nor a hyphen. `^-` matches a hyphen at the beginning and `-$` on the end of the string. The pipes are "ors" i.e. `a|b` matches if pattern `a` matches of if pattern `b` matches.

Comment: this works!  thank you so much!  and, thanks so much for taking the time to explain it to a novice......much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `translate()`

```
...
WHERE translate(Phone_Number,'a1234567890-', 'a') is NOT NULL
```

This will strip out all valid characters leaving behind the invalid ones.  If all the characters are valid, the result would be NULL.  This does not validate the format, for that you'd need to use REGEXP_LIKE or something similar.

Comment: what if `a` exists in the column?

Comment: In the above translate statement, a gets translated to itself, so it would still result in a positive match.  Oracle's translate function has a quirk in that does nothing in the 3rd parameter is null or empty, so to get around that you include at least one character in the 3rd parameter that when translated will meet the needed criteria.

Comment: suppose that the inpit string is 542a233-2770 your translate will validate this as positive, but actually it is not valid phone number

Comment: By positive match I mean the predicate will evaluate to true and return the record, meaning that there is a problem with the phone number. `translate('542a122-2770','a1234567890-','a')` will evaluate to 'a' which is not null.

Comment: Oh, Ok. I got it. My bad. Sorry for that :|

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has `REGEXP_LIKE` for regex compares:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(phone_num,'[^0-9''\-]')
```

If you're unfamiliar with regular expressions, there are plenty of good sites to help you build them.  I like [this one](https://regex101.com/r/ErZTEZ/1)

Comment: thank you so much - appreciate sharing the site to help build.  learning and appreciate all the help i can get!