# Find phone numbers with unexpected characters using SQL

Tags: sql, select, db2

I posted the same question below for SQL in Oracle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876676/how-to-find-phone-numbers-with-unexpected-characters-using-sql-in-oracle) and was provided the SQL info within that works.

However, I now need to perform the same in a DB2 database and if I attempt to run the same SQL it errors out.

I need to find rows where the phone number field contains unexpected characters.

Most of the values in this field look like:

```
123456-7890
```

This is expected. However, we are also seeing character values in this field such as * and #.

I want to find all rows where these unexpected character values exist.

Expected:

1. Numbers are expected
2. Hyphen with numbers is expected (hyphen alone is not)
3. NULL is expected
4. Empty is expected

This SQL works in Oracle:

```
...
WHERE regexp_like(phone_num, '[^ 0123456789-]|^-|-$')
```

When using the same SQL above in DB2, the statement errors out.

Comment: Howdy. Please post the error message you are seeing and the version of DB2 you are using. [This article](https://www.idug.org/p/bl/et/blogaid=605) confirms that the [REGEXP_LIKE predicate](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzregexp_like.htm) is available since version 11.1.

Comment: Are the following strings correct as well? 1. `0123-` 2. `-0123` 3. `01-23-34` 4. `0 1 - 2 3`

Answer (score 1):

I found it easiest to answer your question by phrasing a regex which matches the positive cases.  Then, we can just use `NOT` to find the negative cases.  DB2 supports a `REGEXP_LIKE` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    NOT REGEXP_LIKE(phone_num, '^[0-9]+(-?[0-9]+)*$') AND
    COALESCE(phone_num, '') <> '';
```

Here is a demo of the regex:

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

For newer version of db2, regexp is the way to go. If you are on an older version (perhaps why you get an error), you can replace all accepted chars with '' and check if the result is an empty string. Can't check right now, but from memory, it would be

```
WHERE TRANSLATE(phone_num, '', '0123456789-')<>''
```

EDIT:

For what it's worth your regexp works for V11 so you probably have an older version of Db2. Example of translate and regexp side by side:

```
]$ db2 "with t(s) as ( values '123456-7890', '12345*-7890' ) 
select s, 'regexp' as method from t 
where regexp_like(s, '[^ 0123456789-]|^-|-$') 
union all 
select s, 'translate' as method 
from t where TRANSLATE(s, '', '0123456789-')<>''"

S           METHOD   
----------- ---------
12345*-7890 translate
12345*-7890 regexp   

2 record(s) selected.
```